# Yii active query - Compare Multiple values IN array for a many to many relation

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have tables property and property_has_feature

property_has_feature table looks like this.

```
+-------------+--------------+
| property_id | feature_code |
+-------------+--------------+
|         111 |  PENT        |
|         122 |  GREEN       |
|         122 |  HFLO        |
|         123 |  CCAR        |
|         111 |  CCAR        |
|         111 |  XBLKV       |
|         122 |  MFLO        |
|         122 |  HFLO        |
|         111 |  BILL        |
|         122 |  CCAR        |
+-------------+--------------+
```

I want the list of properties that has a set of features.

For example, I want properties with features PENT, CCAR and BILL. This should give me the property with id 111 as it as all the 3 features mentioned.

I tried the following,

```
        $featureCodes = ['PENT', 'CCAR', 'BILL'];
        $query = Property::find()
        ->where(['status'=> '1'])
        ->joinWith('propertyHasFeatures')
        ->andWhere(['property_has_feature.feature_code'=>$featureCodes]);
```

But this will not give the desired result, Instead, returns all the properties that have at least on the features specified in the array.

How to write the Active query for getting properties with all the give features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the answer.**
This is a bit tricky, You will not get it with a simple IN clause. That returns properties even if the property has one of the features in the list. What we need is properties that have all features in the given array.

```
    $featureCodes = ['PENT', 'CCAR', 'BILL'];
    $query = Property::find()
    ->where(['status'=> '1'])
    ->joinWith('propertyHasFeatures')
    ->andWhere(['property_has_feature.feature_code'=>$featureCodes])
    ->groupBy('property.id')
    ->having(' count(distinct property_has_feature.feature_code) = '.count($featureCodes));
```

Answer (score -1):

$featureCodes is an array so you have to pass it in IN clause

Change your andWhere condition to

```
$featureCodes = ['PENT', 'CCAR', 'BILL'];
    $query = Property::find()
    ->where(['status'=> '1'])
    ->joinWith('propertyHasFeatures')
    ->andWhere(['IN','property_has_feature.feature_code',$featureCodes]);
```

Comment: This will return all the properties which have at least one of the features.  What I want is properties that have all the features in the array. Your code gives the same output because when array is given its taken as IN operator in Yii even if you dont specify IN explicitly.